# Making 2 AJAX jquery to work synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have requirement to manage 2 AJAX jQuery functions to start a process in the server and get the status from the server.

I,e. The first AJAX JQuery which will send a request to the server to start a particular process and returns back to the client with the status 'process-running'.  The second AJAX JQuery function which will be called inside the success block of first function and its responsibility to query the status until it gets the response 'process-complete'.

Here is the psedo code I have

```
//This function which will be called on a button click
function buildApplication(){
  //show the gif spinner in the front-end
  $.when(buildApp()).then(function(result){
    console.log('process-completed');
    //hide the gif spinner in the front-end
  });
}

function buildApp(){
  return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url pointing to php script',
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
        if(result == 'process-running'){
          console.log('monitor starts');
          getAppStatus();
          console.log('monitor ends');
        }
     },
     error: function(result){
     }
   });  
}

function getAppStatus(){
    console.log('Querying server');
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url pointing to php script', 
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
        if(result == 'process-running'){
          getAppStatus();
        }
     },
     error: function(result){
     }
   });
}
```

The sleeping process is handled inside the PHP script of getAppStatus.  I.e, If process is still running then the server will sleep for 10 seconds and then only returns response to the client.

The problem is both the functions are running asynchronous.  That means the buildApp function invokes the getAppStatus function and just returns back immediately.  The getAppStatus function runs as an orphan process.

How can I make it both synchronous (or similar) so that the parent caller will wait till the child to return back?

Note: I tried the `async:false` in the getAppStatus function but it freezes the browser and the ajax loader image stops spinning and it looks like hanged.

Comment: I suggest you use promises to manage this.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @cgatian Unfortunately we cannot use that because the Promise is not supported by Android browsers.  Any other alternatives...

Comment: If you're using jQuery it includes promises http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/